# Find Lengths of Lines of Equivalent Values in Excel

Tags: excel, line, recurrence

I'm working on some Recurrence Quantification Analysis (more info here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_quantification_analysis) and would like to compute the laminarity and trapping time of a time series I have to work with. I am trying to port my working Python code to Excel but am having trouble figuring out a combination of functions that will allow me to figure out the lengths of horizontal lines of '1's generated out of my code (horizontal lines = vertical lines for a simple recurrence plot).

As an example, say my recurrence plot (really just an array of booleans) looks like this:

```
1 1 0 0 1
1 1 1 1 0
1 0 1 1 0
0 1 0 1 1
1 0 1 1 1
```

How do I count the lengths of all the lines that are formed by '1's? Ideally, my output would look something like this:

```
1   4
2   3
3   1
4   1
```

because there are 4 length-1 lines, 3 length-2 lines, etc. If anyone can shed light on this, I would greatly appreciate it. If the solution requires VBA, I'd be more than happy to acquaint myself with it for this purpose.

Comment: Can you explain more about your expected result.

Comment: Ideally, the program will scan each row and determine how long each "row" of '1's is inside there. The sample output for the input is given above. If the algorithm is only applied to the first line, it would count one row of 2 and one row of 1 '1's. The second would give only one row of 4 '1's. The third would give one row of 1 and one row of 2 '1's, etc. I hope the pattern is more evident now.

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be best done in VBA (maybe), but it could certainly done with worksheet formula's too. It just gets a bit ugly.

You can do this in the worksheet by building a couple of complimentary matrices to log starts and ends of your rows (columns) of 1's. They'll look something like:

[image]

The ugly part is the formulas underneath. There is a lot of nesting IF's here, but it shouldn't be overwhelming since you've been doing something similar in python. Below I show the formulas for the first column of the two helper matrices and the final counting formulas. The `IF`s can probably be cleaned up a bit so the logic flows more naturally, but this is a good (and working) first pass:

*quick note to ignore the apostrophe/single-quotes in front of the equal signs `'=` in the formulas in here. I did a quick find/replace to get the formulas to show up for screen print and screwed it up.

[image]

Those formulas are:

For the start/end/stend matrix:

```
=IF(A1=1,  IF(AND(A6<>"", A2=0), "end", IF(A6<>"","x", IF(A2=0, "stend", "start"))),"")
```

For the row size matrix:

```
=IF(A7="start", MATCH("end", A7:A11,0), IF(A7="stend", 1, 0))
```

And for the final tally:

```
=COUNTIF($A$13:$E$17,A19)
```

You can just copy those across the rows and columns in excel to make them fit your matrix size (and adjust the ranges where necessary). I would explain them more in depth, but they are really just a bunch of boring nested ifs. The only parts that are funky are the "Stend" being used to say that this is a single sized row (column) of 1's, and the `Match()` formula, which will return the number of rows down that excel first finds the value being searched in the range specified, which is sort of 100% perfect for this scenario.

If you would like to see some VBA, hit me in the comments and I can whip something up.

Comment: This Looks great. If you could please sketch up a basic skeleton of what I would need to do in VBA, that would be very helpful. Thanks!